# On.(click) not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an `on click` function which fires an ajax call, the on click function does not fire, I have used:

```
.click(function(){
```

Which works but I need the buttons to be able to click more than once so I tried:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#post").on('click', function(){
      alert("JQuery Running!");
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "do.php",
        data: { c: $(this).attr("value") },
        success: function(html){
          $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
          $("#add_err").html(html);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<div class='err' id='add_err'></div>
<button id='post' value='1' />Do</button>
```

I have also tried:

```
$(document).on('click', '#post', function(){})
```

Which also does not work and my console.log is always showing:

```
Uncaught Typeerror: $(...).on is not a function 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? IIRC, `.on()` was implemented around version 1.8.

Comment: try `$('body').on('click', '#post', function(){`

Comment: @chaos505 thanks for your suggestion still the same console error

Comment: Your code seems to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/pecr65cx/

Comment: Just tried what you said through jsfidle and that seems to have the same issue aswell https://jsfiddle.net/1619kfkh/

Comment: could you show your jquery declare

Comment: Are you sure that is the only script referenced on your page? this sounds awefull lot like you have 1.7 < somewhere. I can't figure why else it would complain about `.on()`. if you use chrome, open dev tools, go to network tab/show filters/click js/look for jquery references there

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that is the only script referenced on your page? this sounds awefull lot like you have 1.7 < somewhere. I can't figure why else it would complain about `.on()` .

if you use chrome, 
1) open dev tools 
2) go to network tab
3) show filters
4) click js 
5) look for jquery references there

[Screen how to do (stackoverflow.com)](http://screencast.com/t/1ouTNLh2wY)

Answer (score 1):

If you use an old jquery version (<1.7) you can use bind:

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: I'm Using jquery 2.2.0

Comment: @user6044058 clearly you are not. Maybe you're using two versions at once?

Comment: No check all my files that are included and the standard file and they are only using the 2.2.0 library

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you have put your click script *after* you have referenced jQuery on the page, not before.

Comment: It jquery is declared before

Comment: OK, if the jQuery library is referenced in the <head> section of the document, but if it is referenced using @RenderSection() on a master page, or the page you call that holds your click script is an ajax rendered page, this can sometimes not be so straightforward to see. Is your jQuery library referenced in <head> ?